# When designing on my Macbook Pro using bright colours, the colours appear dull when AirDropped to iPhone - how can I match the colours?

Tags: iphone

When I design on my 2018 Macbook Pro using Figma I'm using some very bright colours which appear super vibrant and amazing.

When I export as PNG and AirDrop it to my phone the colours are very dull and ugly.

I'm guessing its something to do with RGB/sRGB but could someone explain how (if at all) that I can view this brighter colour style on my iPhone X?

Thanks!

Comment: You say you save it as PNG. PNG 8 bits? PNG 32 bits? PNG 24 bits?  
Do the colours look flat if you open the PNG again on the Macbook?

Assuming that that is not it, do they look flat on all other devices? No idea what airdrop does, but windows/android do nasty things when moving data between them, they reencode some things in the name of security and efficiency, forcing workarounds to be needed. No idea if airdrop does the same.

Comment: Last but not least: colours never look the same on different devices. Each display if different. With some luck you have a well calibrated IPS screen on all devices and they all look almost the same, but once you tosss in a phone display all bets are off.

 If you save it as 'PNG' and open it on another desktop. Did the colours change? If they did then ignore the iPhone part.